# Deedy Resume; How do you unbold the Last Name of the Title

Tags: xetex, cv, deedy-resume

How would you format the last name of the Title that I have circled above to not be bolded? [image: Example]

Comment: For a one off, try `{\normalfont Das}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to the preamble of the document will result in the last name being shown in the same font/color as the first name:

```
\renewcommand{\namesection}[3]{ % Defines the command for the main heading
\centering{ % Center the name
\fontsize{40pt}{60pt} % Font size
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Hai}\selectfont #1 % First name font
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Hai}\selectfont #2 % Last name font
} \\[5pt] % Whitespace between the name and contact information
\centering{ % Center the contact information
\color{headings} % Use the headings color
\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont #3} % Contact information font
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\color{headings}\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}} % Horizontal rule
\vspace{-5pt} % Reduce whitespace after the rule slightly
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. You need to open the cls file and search for namesection
2. swap the font names Lig -> Hai to make the 1st word bold and 2nd word normal.
3. if you want both words normal use "Hai" instead of Lig.

`%\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont #1  %\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Hai}\selectfont #2`